# displaying of records in text box not displaying

Tags: php, html

in my html form i have a stext box called Province. now, when i tried to echo it there's nothing is displaying

**PHP**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

$Province = isset($_GET['Province']) ? $_GET['Province'] : '';

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$Province = $_POST['Province'];

if($LTS->update($Province))
{
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Updated!');</script>";
}
else
{
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Update Failed!');   </script>";
}
  }

  if(isset($_GET['SFUND_ID']))
  {
    $SFUND_ID = $_GET['SFUND_ID'];
    extract($LTS->getID($SFUND_ID));
  }
?>
```

**here is the updated code**
**class.user.php**

```
 public function getID($SFUND_ID)
 {
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sfund WHERE SFUND_ID=:SFUND_ID");
 $stmt->execute(array(":SFUND_ID"=>$SFUND_ID));
 $editRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 return $editRow;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="Province" value="<?php echo $Province; ?>">
```

Comment: is PHP file different than HTML file? or both of your codes(html and php) are in same file? Just ruling out the possibility that maybe you are using two different files when your both code has to be in same file whose extension is .php and php code should come before HTML.

Comment: its in the same page.yeah its on the top of the HTML

Comment: Replace your HTML code with :
`<input name="Province" value="<?php var_dump($Province); ?>">`
see what it shows.

Comment: i tried it but it shows this <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i></pre>

Comment: Please check $Province has any value or not

Comment: it has a value inside my database

Comment: Result of `var_dump()` clears that your string `$Province` is not getting any value at the first place. Its an empty string. Double check your PHP code. like `var_dump()` values of `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables to see if they are having any values to put in `$Province`.

Comment: let me update my question i will my class

Comment: i get this string '' (length=0)

Comment: So you need to check the file which is sending the parameter `$Povince` to this PHP file because your `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables are not carrying the value of `$Province`

Comment: how can i check that?